# How do i set a key field when creating table in KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I would like to ask can i set the key field when creating table?

I have created a table by aggregation as below:

```
CREATE TABLE withdrawal_less_than_5min AS 
SELECT executedate, status, count(*) as count 
FROM TB3_WITHDRAW_RECORD_EXCLUDE_INTERNAL_USERS 
GROUP BY executedate,status;
```

And when I `DESCRIBE EXTENDED withdrawal_less_than_5min` the key field of the table is set as below, which i believe should be the executedate and status.

`Key field            : KSQL_INTERNAL_COL_0|+|KSQL_INTERNAL_COL_1`

However when I try to join it with another table with the same aggregation it return this error.

```
Source table (A) key column (KSQL_INTERNAL_COL_0|+|KSQL_INTERNAL_COL_1) 
is not the column used in the join criteria (EXECUTEDATE).
```

How do I set the key field? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can create key through following way -

```
CREATE TABLE withdrawal_less_than_5min with (key='EXECUTEDATE') AS 
SELECT executedate, status, count(*) as count 
FROM TB3_WITHDRAW_RECORD_EXCLUDE_INTERNAL_USERS 
GROUP BY executedate,status partition by 'EXECUTEDATE';
```

You can follow Robin's blog also - https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/inspecting-changing-topic-keys.

For any errors or question with Ksql, Search Robin Moffet, he has already answered our queries to help :)

Comment: This is returning an error message  `mismatched input 'partition' expecting ';' `

Comment: I'm in the same boat as the OP and CREATE TABLE doesn't like the PARTITION BY clause.